# Do I need a barn for each animal type?

Tags: story-of-seasons

From the looks of things, I can have various animals, like sheep and rabbits and cows and chickens. Do I need a separate barn for each type of animal, or can they cohabitate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! Animals can coexist, but only certain ones.

"Large" Livestock like cows, sheep, horses, etc. go in barns, while smaller animals like chickens and bunnies go in coops. The pet house is for, well, pets. Cats and dogs mostly reside in the pet house.